# cakePHP : Validation Type Date, but only use the Year

Tags: php, date, cakephp, datetime, types

I use the date type in cakePHP, but the user only has to choose a year instead of the day-month-year.

Code in the View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('player_turnedPro', array(
    'type' => 'date',
    'dateFormat' => 'Y',
    'minYear' => date('Y')-100, 
    'maxYear' => date('Y')-0+1, 
    'label' => 'Turned Pro',
    'empty' => '- select -',
    'default' => date('Y')
));
```

Code in the Model :

```
'player_turnedPro' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
```

I have set the type of the database column to DATE.

The problem I have is that the value of the year doesn't come in the database and I get the message: notEmpty under the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom validation like this (will only work for years 100 back and current year + 1, adjust how you need)

```
function validateYear($field) {
    return current($field) > date('Y') - 100 && current($field) < date('Y') + 1;
}
```

Stick that in the model, add to the validation rules

```
'player_turnedPro' => array(
    'notEmpty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
    ),
    'validateYear' => array(
        'rule' => array('validateYear'),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in controllers before check $this->ModelName->validates()

```
if(empty($this->data['player_turnedPro'])){
        $this->ModelName->validationErrors['player_turnedPro'][] = __('Select Year');
}
```